# Android: How to load a GLTF or GLB file from remote URL in filament

Tags: android, kotlin, remote-server, gltf, google-filament

I'm trying to load a remote asset (.glb or .gltf) into the `ModelViewer` in filament. The [Google Filament sample-gltf-viewer](https://github.com/google/filament/blob/main/android/samples/sample-gltf-viewer/src/main/java/com/google/android/filament/gltf/MainActivity.kt) shows a `RemoteServer` object but I'm not seeing how I can load a remote asset from a URL (e.g. https://github.com/kelvinwatson/glb-files/raw/main/DamagedHelmet.glb)

I've tried the below but I get "Unable to parse glb file".

The code for [RemoteServer](https://github.com/google/filament/blob/main/android/filament-utils-android/src/main/java/com/google/android/filament/utils/RemoteServer.javahttps://github.com/google/filament/blob/main/android/filament-utils-android/src/main/java/com/google/android/filament/utils/RemoteServer.java) doesn't indicate where we can pass a URL.

```
val glbUrl = "<URL TO YOUR GLB ASSET>"

private fun loadGlbRemote() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val url = URL(glbUrl)
        val connection = url.openConnection()
        connection.connect()
        val inputStream: InputStream = BufferedInputStream(url.openStream())
        val len = connection.contentLength
        val byteArray = ByteArray(len)
        inputStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
        val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)
        modelViewer.loadModelGlb(byteBuffer)
        inputStream.close()
    }
```

```
implementation 'com.google.android.filament:filament-android:1.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.filament:filament-utils-android:1.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.filament:gltfio-android:1.7.0'`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved. The issue was that I wasn't fully downloading the file, and that the `modelViewer.loadModelGlb` needed to be called on the main thread.

Here is the working code:

```
val glbUrl = "<URL TO YOUR GLB ASSET>"
URL(glbUrl).openStream().use { inputStream: InputStream ->
    val inputStream = BufferedInputStream(inputStream)
    ByteArrayOutputStream().use {  output->
        inputStream.copyTo(output)
        val byteArr = output.toByteArray()
        val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArr)
        val rewound = byteBuffer.rewind()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            modelViewer.destroyModel()
            modelViewer.loadModelGlb(rewound)
            modelViewer.transformToUnitCube()
```

Solution has been included in the filed issue: https://github.com/google/filament/issues/5255